# Weird LS output on WSL2

Tags: files, ls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using `ls` or `exa` I get a weird output on windows subsystem for linux :

[image]

Can someone point out what's wrong? I have no funny aliases here. Just running ls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong; you have a file called `{` in your current directory.

You can rename it or remove it by quoting it. For example `mv '{' whatami`